# Is there a way to manually add custom legend keys with custom rows in ggplot2 with guide_legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I would like to customize the number of rows appear in the legend. Here is my data frame.

```
df = data.frame(label = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M"),
                x = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 5, 3),
                y = c(3, 5, 6, 2, 5, 3, 5, 3, 2, 3, 6, 7, 1, 3))
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = label, group = label, fill = label))  +
  geom_point() + guides(colour = guide_legend(nrow= 3))
```

[image]

But What I really want is the row with 3 nrow followed by 2 nrow. Like this uploaded picture. Any help is appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ncol = 6, byrow = T`.

Before that, you might want to set factor to your "label" column as suggested by @Allan Cameron

```
df$label <- factor(df$label, c("A", "D", "F", "H", "J", "L", "B", "E", "G", "I", "K", "M", "C"))
```

Then `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = label, group = label, fill = label))  +
  geom_point() + guides(colour = guide_legend(nrow = 3, ncol = 6, byrow = T))
```

[image: ggplot]

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer. I would like the first column of the legend to be of A, B, C in place of A, G, M.

Comment: I do not know any easy way of doing so :(

Comment: @benson23 you could reorder the factors so they appear in that order - `df$label <- factor(df$label, c("A", "D", "F", "H", "J", "L", "B", "E", "G", "I", "K", "M", "C"))` and plot again

Comment: It works. Great!

Comment: @Allan Cameron yes the most obvious way to reorder stuff in `ggplot` would be setting factors. But again I don't think it's elegant, especially if you have more than 10 terms that you need to manually type in. Btw thanks for the suggestion :)